# Python stdin causing Run Time Error on Online Judge

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have no clue why this simple piece of code gives me a Run Time Error in an Online Judge. This RTE is caused by stdin. There was a problem in input. But I'm not getting it. This has been so much frustrating. With python3 I've tried many ways to compile and run it. Even manual compile and run like

```
python file.py < input.txt > output.txt
```

from CMD works well, works in IDEONE also, in my PC everywhere but this piece of code causing me RTE in an online judge.

Can anyone tell me, is there anything really wrong that can cause Run Time Error with python3??

Code file with input details can be found [here](https://ideone.com/TcOQin) !

```
def main():
    t = int(input()) # stdin.readline() used before!! ### Taking the first testcase input
    for i in range(0 , t , 1):
        s = input().strip() # stdin.readline() used before!! ### Taking Nth Line as string and stripping it.
        e = s.split(" ") # splitting the string by space.
        l = list(map(int , e)) # converting the whole string list to int list
        si = l.pop(0) # taking the first element
        l.sort()
        print(l) # printing the list

from sys import stdin
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any advice on taking inputs will be warmly welcomed.

I got this error on [toph](https://toph.co).

[image: screenshot of the problem and the code]

Comment: So... what kind of `RuntimeError`? Is there any error message?

Comment: no, they didn't specify.

Comment: Then it's their fault. Runtime errors generally signify errors in underlying C code. Maybe their tests are Python modules written in C and they may be buggy.

Comment: Can you specify the problem URL (iff it is publicly accessible)?